# WARN Exception in thread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 4"

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to use GAListener but every time I do /fakevote I get this error:

Code (Text):

```
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] WARN Exception in thread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 4"
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] WARN org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: Plugin GAListener v1.3.2 generated an exception while executing task 3856
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:56)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bukkit.Server._INVALID_getOnlinePlayers()[Lorg/bukkit/entity/Player;
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at com.swifteh.GAL.RewardTask.run(RewardTask.java:37)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO ... 3 more
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] WARN Exception in thread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 15"
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] WARN org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: Plugin GAListener v1.3.2 generated an exception while executing task 3858
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:56)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bukkit.Server._INVALID_getOnlinePlayers()[Lorg/bukkit/entity/Player;
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at com.swifteh.GAL.RewardTask.run(RewardTask.java:37)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
28.05 21:15:17 [Server] INFO ... 3 more
```

**Solutions I have tried:**

- ClearLags /lagg gc
- Putting the server properties port the same as my
  votifier port
- Checking the votifier settings on voting pages (all of
  the information is correct)

Does anyone have any more solutions?

When a player votes they don't get their rewards, but it still says that voted.

Answer (score 0):

There were recent changes in the Bukkit API regarding the getOnlinePlayers() method. GAListener version 1.3.2 is only compatible with Minecraft 1.9. For your 1.8 version of Minecraft, you have to use version 1.3.1 of the plugin.